# How to use custom classes inside elements in sass

Tags: css, sass

I have declared a css property in sass as below:

```
.submit-link {
     float: left;
    i{         
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
     }
 }
```

Now I need to add a custom class which would be added to the i element. I tried using &.back-to-home within the element i

```
.submit-link {
     float: left;
     i{
        &.back-to-home
        {
          float:right !important;
        }
        float: left;
        display: inline-block;
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
 }
```

But it doesn't work. I tried adding as &:back-to-home too. It didn't work.
How can I add the custom class to the above sass. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. Cheers

Comment: is `back-to-home` a class? Can you show the generated css code and how would you like to be?

Comment: `&.back-to-home` should work fine, the output CSS would show `i.back-to-home`

Comment: It should be working. Post your HTML, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what isn't working for you, but I've created this simple demo and its working fine:

HTML:

```
<i>Test</i>
<i class="back-to-home">Home</i>
```

SCSS:

```
i {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;

  &.back-to-home {
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

jsFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/kr29b1dn/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Then I guess there is some issue with sass compilation. Because the generated css doesn't have the code I added at all. So I thought there would be something syntactically wrong due to which the compiler couldn't recognize the class. Thanks for the answer